# Gdrive don't show up anymore in my file menager

Tags: 22.04, online-accounts, google-drive

after installed "github cli" following it documentation tutorial [by this link](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md), my gdrive stopped working.

I checked my "online accounts" in "settings menu" and my google account is enable.

Gdrive disappeared from file manager app and from sidebar when usually show disks mounteds (printscreens from file menager screen and desktop screen below).

Disks app also show there isn't a gdrive disk.

Someone could help me? please.

I started to use linux distributions less thans a year. I installed ubuntu 6 month ago.

[file menager printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoZIx.png)

[desktop printscreeen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BwY1.jpg)

[online account registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgJid.png)

[disk app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxvHQ.png)

Comment: Where did you get the idea Google Drive is supposed to appear in Disks? It isn't. Even if Google Drive had an Linux client with a dedicated sync folder - it hasn't - that wouldn't appear in the Disks tool which is for local drives. Having your Google account setup in online accounts should give a *view* of your data in Files, the file manager, not Disks.

Comment: It was show in Disks. Before I installed 'github cli' Disks showed my Gdrive account as a mounted disk in my computer. Disks even showed how many space available I had in Gdrive. But, thanks for comment, I edited my post to be more clear about the problem.